# An old favorite game

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I came across an old favorite computer game the other day, downloaded it and started playing. Must say I think it still holds and can see why it was a star among the games I played as a teenager. Can you find the name of the game from the, rather elementary, Sudoku below?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Sudoku solution:

> [image]

And

> as hinted by "elementary", we can convert the highlighted numbers to chemical elements. These are `Ac La P H Ag C Er N Ta Al U Rn I`, and the first letters of these are **`ALPHA CENTAURI`**.

Comment: Nicely done! The "star" in the text was a little confirmation hint as well.